# what is pip-req-build temp folder used for? Can I prevent using it?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

When installing a python package on Windows from source code using `pip install .`, a temp folder named `pip-req-build-RANDOM_STRING` will be created under `%USERPROFILE%/AppData`. I want to know what is this folder used for? Seems some source code files are copied here and setup.py is run here. Sometimes it causes errors. 
For example, with following project structure:

`gitrepo
 ├ a.txt
 └ package_name
    ├ setup.py
    └ ...`

If `a.txt` is required in `setup.py` by `open('../a.txt')`, then `pip install .` under `gitrepo/package_name` will cause error.

Why we have to build the source code in a temp folder? Is there anyway I can prevent this?

BTW, I want to use `pip install .` to install the package instead of `python setup.py install`.

Comment: When using tox "pip install" is even enforced

Comment: My directorystructure is simpler: the textfile used from ``setup.py`` is located in the same directory as ``setup.py`` but it results in the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a Python package using pip, it typically first builds the package from source code, and then installs the resulting build artifacts (such as Python files, compiled extensions, etc.) into your Python environment.

The reason that pip builds the package in a temporary directory is to avoid any conflicts or interference with the package's source code directory. This is because the build process may modify or add files to the package directory, which could cause problems if you try to build or install the package again from the same directory.

In the case of the error you described, it's likely that the relative path "../a.txt" is being resolved relative to the temporary build directory rather than the original package directory, which is causing the error. One way to avoid this issue is to use an absolute path to the file instead.

To answer your question about whether there's a way to prevent pip from building the package in a temporary directory, the short answer is no, there isn't. This behavior is built into pip's implementation and is not configurable.

However, if you want to install the package without using pip's build process, you can use the command "python setup.py install" instead. This will run the package's setup script directly and install the resulting build artifacts into your Python environment. Note that this method may not always work if the package has complex build requirements or dependencies that are not available in your environment.